# Example of a continuous function which is not smooth

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

> I need a function which is continuous but not smooth ( not a $C^{\infty})$.

Smooth functions are those  whose derivatives of all order exists. For example $f(x)= e^{x}$ is a smooth function  while $f(x)=|x|$ is not smooth as derivative at $0$ does not exist.

But what I require is functions in from $\mathbb{R}^{n} $ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

For simplicity it is enough to give functions from $\mathbb{R}^{2} $ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I have examples of discontinuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^{2} $ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ , like $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$  which is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: What if you consider step functions?

Comment: off top of my head..a wiener process? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process

Comment: as an example of a (deterministic) function that is continuous but nowhere differentiable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: @ Anthony Step functions are not continuous.I need continuous functions  which can be differentiable up to  some order (at least second ) but not for higher orders.

Comment: Would the nth anti-derivative of the  Koch curve fulfil this requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ given by

$f(x,y)=(|x-y|,|x+y|)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$.

$f$ is continuous since both $f_1,f_2$ are so.

Now $f$ is not differentiable since $f_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

The partial derivative of $f_1$ at $(0,0)$ :
$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f_1(h,0)-f_1(0,0)}{h}=\dfrac{|h|}{h}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Your example $x\mapsto|x|$, mapping $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ continuously but not smoothly, can be trivially upgraded to map $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ continuously but not smoothly: $(x,y)\mapsto(|x|,y)$.  ($(x,y)\mapsto(|x|,|y|)$ works too.) The same ideas can be used for higher-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Such functions are commonly used in approximations, such as by piecewise polynomials/splines.  For example we might "triangulate" a region of the plane and create piecewise linear functions on the triangles that globally form a continuous  but not differentiable function.  Linear interpolation between corners of triangles will accomplish this.

This readily generalizes to maps $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by subdividing a region of $n$-space into conforming simplices, i.e. that meet face to face.  Once again an arbitrary assignment of values at the collected vertices extends to a continuous (but typically not smooth) function on the whole region by linear interpolation, often implemented via [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system).

Obtaining vector-valued functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ in this way is easy; we have no particular requirements that separate "output" coordinates should be related in any way (as far as this Question is concerned).

Obtaining higher-order continuity, e.g. continuity of the first- and second-order derivatives, is a bigger challenge.  The need for such things often comes up in the context of [finite element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) approximations.

One of the easier ways to obtain interpolations that have continuous first derivatives is with [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) on a regular (rectangular) grid.